# c++ boost threading issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I am quite new to C++ multithreading. I have the following flow of code:

Main Thread:

- Creates a queue
- Creates a Second Thread
- Adds items to the queue
- Ends

Second Thread:

- If queue has items, pops it.
  (the second thread exits when a flag is set to exit).

The problem is, once main function finishes adding items to queue, it stops. Adding a .join() after creating the second thread would just make it to hang infinitely.

Can anyone describe a way to work this out?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As you seem to have set up a _"secondary front"_ of threads you should `join()` these first.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the second thread is not *seeing* the 'exit' flag.

Be sure to synchronize access to it or make it a `atomic_bool`, e.g.